# How to set id's for dynamic rows in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have created a dynamic table using ngtable , and table data for 3 columns is fetched from json.In that table for 4th column a green/red color circle should come based on connection if successful or not.
The same i have done with javascript(without using json) in which for that 4th column i have set the four different id's,and based on id's i have changed the color using ajax if connection is successful.
In angular using json i m unable to do so , I have created the dynamic table but how to set id's and from where to get the image i'm unable to do.Can anyone help on this.

```
<table ng-table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Feature</th>
<th>DaysUp</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
<td>{{user.name}}</td>
<td>{{user.status}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>    
</table>
```

Comment: u have any jsfiddle demo for wat u have done so far ?

Comment: Can you please try to simplify your question and clearly explain what you are trying to do and what your expected html output is? Also please post your json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scope id and index value to generate unique id. As ng-repeat creates child scope so you will get one scope id(unique id of scope) that id you can attach with $index.

```
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users" id="{{$parent.$id+'-'+$index}}">
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.status}}</td>
        </tr>
```

[***JSFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/q2bjagmp/)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">

    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>DaysUp</td>
            <td>Status</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.daysup}}</td>
            <td><img width="20px" height="20px" ng-src="{{imageurls[user.status-1]}}" /> </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

SCript:

```
angular.module('myapp',[])
            .controller('myctrl',function($scope){
                $scope.users =[
                    {'name':'xyz','daysup':2,'status':1},
                    {'name':'abc','daysup':4,'status':2},
                    {'name':'klm','daysup':6,'status':3},
                    {'name':'yrt','daysup':9,'status':4}
                ];
                $scope.imageurls = [
                        'http://www.wpclipart.com/blanks/buttons/glossy_buttons/glossy_button_blank_yellow_circle.png',
                        'http://pix.iemoji.com/sbemojix2/0702.png',
                        'http://clker.com/cliparts/u/g/F/R/X/9/green-circle-md.png',
                        'http://pix.iemoji.com/sbemojix2/0701.png'
                ];

            });
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9DipkwWv3962s8KAUVdj)